# Get all projects that have executed a custom gradle script

Tags: gradle

Just like we can do the following:

```
allprojects {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {...}
}
```

When our projects call this function:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

could we do the same for custom scripts?

i.e. those applied with:

```
apply from: "$rootProjectDir/gradle/someCustomScript.gradle"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported for binary plugins, but not for script plugins.